# I bought a iPhone 5, but didn't know the home screen was locked

Tags: password, iphone

I bought a used iPhone 5 not knowing it was locked. What do I do,I've tried to restore it by holding the power an home button but it's  still locked.

Comment: Contact the seller

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to defeat an iCloud lock.  Return the phone to the point of purchase.